# Django Rest Framework: How can I create endpoint for logging via Gmail (Google)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am trying to create API and I'm wondering how I can create an endpoint for authenticating via Gmail account. Seems like `django-rest-auth` supports only Facebook and Twitter.

Anyone could give me tips?

Comment: this will help you  [django-social-auth](https://pypi.org/project/django-social-auth/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Django rest auth in one of my projects and it does support Google sign-in.
It supports all the social provider which `django-allauth` supports.
[Here](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#google) is the list of the supported social provider by django-allauth and django-rest-auth

```
# social_auth_view.py

from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.views import GoogleOAuth2Adapter
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView

class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter

# urls.py
urlpatterns += [
    ...,
    url(r'^rest-auth/google/$', GoogleLogin.as_view(), name='google_login')
]
```

So, If you want to support any other social provider.

1. Import adapter for your social provider from `allauth.socialaccount.providers`.
2. Create new view as a subclass of `rest_auth.registration.views.SocialLoginView`.
3. Add the adapter imported in step 1 in the view as `adapter_class` attribute.
4. Import this view in urls.py

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that. The way the official doc writes is confusing. I will try it soon!

Comment: Actually I have a question. The form requires to input Code and Access Token. How can I test if it actually works like by inputting actual gmail account or something?

Comment: You can get access token from here. https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Answer (score 0):

Try [django-rest-framework-social-oauth2](https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2)